# In Entity Framework can you name an Entity Set differently to it's table?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Simple question really. As part of some data structure changes that I've been making, I've moved the mapping of one of our Entity Framework sets from a View to a Database table. To get this working quickly and ensure proof of concept I just changed the name of the DB Table to match the expected Entity Set Name and then made my other changes. Changing the actual name of the Entity Set caused a ripple of mismatches (and thus errors) through the code.

This worked fine and I'm happy with the new code. However ideally I'd prefer to be able to change the mapping rather than the name of the table on our live servers. Is it possible to make an Entity Set map to a table without having the name of the Set match the name of the DB table?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can edit the data model XML directly.  Or, in the designer, you can edit the name of entity set using the Properties window and you can edit the mapping using the Mapping Details window.  In the Mapping Details window, just select the table to map to, then map the columns to the properties.

Comment: I'm confused. When I go to table mapping, it only gives me one option, and that's the name of the old View that powered the data set. How/where do I change this to give me the required options?

Comment: @Matt: You need to get the table into the storage layer of the entity data model.  The easiest way to do this is to run the "Update Model From Database" command from the context menu in the entity designer, and select the new table.  This will add an additional entity for the new table.  Since you don't actually want to use this entity, you can delete it in the designer.  But, since that action loaded the table schema into the storage layer, you should now be able to change the mapping of your original entity using the Mapping Details window.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for that - I had assumed I needed to keep the original entity. But it still doesn't give me what I want which is a way to keep both DB tables and my original code references intact. If I change the Entity Set name then the references to the Entity set in the existing code all need to change. I can do that of course, but I was hoping to avoid it. Perhaps it's not possible. But thanks for trying.

Comment: @Matt: Maybe I didn't explain it clearly enough.  You don't need to change the name of the entity set.  You need to add the new database table as a second entity -- temporarily.  This is just to get the table structure into the storage layer of the entity framework.  You can add it by hand to the XML file, but using the designer is easier and faster.  Then, when you delete the new temporary entity, the database table structure remains in the storage layer allowing you to re-map the existing entity without changing its name.  Therefore, you don't need to change any references in your code.

Comment: is it possible to change after compiled?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Just select the entity in the designer and change the `Entity Set Name` in the properties window.

You can call it anything you want.

Comment: This also changes the name of the DbSet property in the DbContext, which is not what everyone would want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Table attribute on your entity, no?

```
[Table(Name = "MY_TABLE")]
public class MyTable
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: This looks useful, but I can't find any documentation on MSDN. Is there anything I can look at?

Comment: No. That's for LINQ to SQL. It's not useful for EF.